# How can getViewSite().getWorkbenchWindow() make sense if the IViewSite class does not have any children?

Tags: java, eclipse, api, eclipse-rcp

I read in the docs that `IViewSite` is a children-less interface, so how can an object of type `IViewSite` execute  the `getWorkbenchWindow()` method if it does not have any child class to implement it?

(In the docs it says that this class is not supposed to be implemented by clients; but it does not have any other premade children)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the type hierarchy of `IViewSite` (Open the class, then hit `CTRL-T`). It will show you an implementation class `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewSite`.
The docs basically say that this should not concern you.